# Azure Website Error 502

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Webforms Application on Azure but i always get the following Error on some sites:
**502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**

I already read a lot of topics regarding the 502 error on Azure but i still don't understand what the problem in my particular situation is.

The error occurs just on some site of the application. I can always reproduce the following pattern:

- Open SITENAME.azurewebsites.net                  -> Error occurs
- Open SITENAME.azurewebsites.net/Site1.aspx       -> Error not occuring
- Open SITENAME.azurewebsites.net/Site2.aspx       -> Error not occuring
- Refresh SITENAME.azurewebsites.net/Site2.aspx    -> Error occurs and won't go away until i call Site1.aspx again

The only thing i found in the log is, that the application loads System.Windows.Forms.dll and there is an AccessViolationException. I have no idea why this dll is loaded at all because there is no Reference in any Project in Visual Studio to it but thats another story :).

But what i don't understand is that the error 502 does not always occur on Site 502.
Maybe someone can give me a hint what might be the problem or how i could find it...

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**
What i forgot to mention: In some threads regarding this error i read, that it occurs after 3 minutes or something like that. In my case it is nearly alway about 25 seconds until the errormessage shows up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That points to an application issue. The reason you are etting 502 is because the worker process is crashing and  the front end is left with a request with no response and returning a 502 to say exactly that. Look for `eventlog.xml` under the LogFiles folder for your website. Alternatively you can try [remote debugging from VS to your website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

`System.Windows.Forms.dll` contains a lot of UI code that will most probably not work Azure websites sandbox. The reason it's loaded is probably because you are using something from the assembly or using something that uses something from that assembly. It doesn't have to be listed in Visual Studio to be loaded since it's a part of the standard .NET Framework.

I would suggest looking into remote debugging and figuring out at what point this is getting loaded and why.

Comment: thanks for our answer! I tried remote debugging but i did not get very far because i run into the AccessViolationException right after startup :). Regarding the Windows.Forms.dll: is it possible, that System.Drawing.dll is causing Windows.Forms to load?

Comment: yes, what are you using from System.Drawing? System.Drawing uses a lot of GDI+ code which is blocked by Azure Sandbox. In general most UI code will be blocked because it depends on kernel calls that are blocked. And in general you shouldn't need it in server code. if you are just using helper functions from System.Drawing then their might be alternatives else where

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I got 502 errors because the site was restarted by the azure auto-heal system. It turns out I made tests with that auto-heal system a few days ago, but since in the end I disabled it, I didn't think it could cause my 502 errors.

This is where I discovered that the azure interface to change auto-heal settings (mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/Support -> mitigate) only affects the production slot. But when you swap your deployment slots, the settings get swapped. There is apparently no way to directly change the staging slot settings, you have to swap, change settings, and swap again.

So, I ended up having my staging slot with auto-heal enabled, and my production slot with auto-heal disabled (and of course at that time I thought it was disabled on both slots). Then I was "randomly" hitting 502 errors either on staging or production depending on how many times I swapped them. What's weird is that though the application seems to restart (or at least fails to respond to a few requests), I don't get the corresponding events in my log file, like if it wasn't running Application_Start after an app pool recycle triggered by the auto-heal system.

Took me a whole day to find out what was happening, I hope this answer can help someone in the same situation.

Comment: I have found a bug on SWAP reported to Microsoft where the requests were not routed to the correct web server. They should have a fix within a month writing this message. I believe this bug was there for a while.

Comment: Hi @jsgoupil, same thing happens to me when swapping... do you know if it has already been corrected?

Comment: @Subgurim I believe this is fixed. I have been swapping without any problem now. I haven't run my tester though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error for a while after fiddling with connection strings, went away and came back in an hour, and the issue had disappeared and the site worked normally again.  A highly technical answer for you.